# Altium Designer, change decimal separator

Tags: altium

I'm wondering if it is possible to change the decimal separator in Altium Designer from a "." to a ","? I have looked for it and Googled it but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible. But you can change the "comma" on your numeric keyboard to make a "dot" with the following registry entry:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,34,00,53,00,00,00,00,00
```

Save this to a file named comma.reg, execute it and when asked, allow Windows to add the changes to the registry.

Answer (score 1):

Since my first post I have found these bug reports on the Altium website which confirms that only the "dot" is valid as a decimal separator:

http://bugcrunch.live.altium.com/Bug/72

http://bugcrunch.live.altium.com/#Bug/273

http://bugcrunch.live.altium.com/#Bug/435

Answer (score 1):

You could also put your values in the old school way. For example, 6.8k (sorry, 6,8k) would be entered as 6k8.